# How can i check exists Preferences in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

In my application I want save some data and I want save this data into `SharedPrefernces`.
For this issue I create one class and write below codes into this class :

```
public class SharedPrefrencesHandler {
    private Context context;

    public SharedPrefrencesHandler(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void setToShared(String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public String getFromShared(String key) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        String value = preferences.getString(key, "");
        return value;
    }
}
```

With below codes, I check is not empty `editTexts`, save this **texts** into `preferences` class :

```
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(loginEdtTxts.get(0).getText().toString()) &&
                    !TextUtils.isEmpty(loginEdtTxts.get(1).getText().toString())) {
                usernameStr = loginEdtTxts.get(0).getText().toString();
                passwordStr = loginEdtTxts.get(1).getText().toString();

                prefrencesHandler.setToShared(SharedPrefrencesKeys.USERNAME.name(), usernameStr);
                prefrencesHandler.setToShared(SharedPrefrencesKeys.PASSWORD.name(), passwordStr);
```

I want in **mainActivity**, first check this `preferences`, if exist data (before save by user) show **Ok** `toast` and when not exists show **Error** `toast`.

How can I it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `preferences.getString(key, null)==null` to check if a key exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
String prefUserName = prefrencesHandler.getFromShared(SharedPrefrencesKeys.USERNAME.name());
String prefPassword = prefrencesHandler.getFromShared(SharedPrefrencesKeys.PASSWORD.name());
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(prefUserName) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(prefPassword)) {
        // Ok code
    } else {
       // Err code
}
```

I hope help you